# Adb version check in eclipse

Tags: android, adt

[image]Installed adb drivers from motorola. i found these note in android eclipse

*When you connect a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher to your computer, the system shows a dialog asking whether to accept an RSA key that allows debugging through this computer. This security mechanism protects user devices because it ensures that USB debugging and other adb commands cannot be executed unless you're able to unlock the device and acknowledge the dialog. This requires that you have adb version 1.0.31 (available with SDK Platform-tools r16.0.1 and higher) in order to debug on a device running Android 4.2.2 or higher*.

Question is how to find adb version and when I connect mobile it doesn't ask me RSA key?

Comment: Click on Help menu --> About ADT

Comment: i found only"  Android Developer Tools 22.0.5.v201307292155--757759 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product"

Comment: I could not able to find it where is it exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use a command,

if you use windows, open a CMD, if on Linux use a terminal
navigate to the sdk folder, and run the command `adb version`

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx>f:

F:\>cd adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321

F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321>cd sdk

F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk>cd platform-tools

F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools>adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29

F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools>
```

and make sure you have enabled `Usb Debugging` on the mobile